# android arraylist won't refresh on runnnig app

Tags: android

my app consist of a main activity with 3 fragments and I have an arraylist of boolean type in the second fragment of grid adapter  to check the states of checkbox in every position so an action could be done in the first fragment.
the issue is that the arreylist never updates and it keeps the same data values 
my code is below

```html
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<GridWord> list;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkBoxState;
    public boolean status;




    GridAdapter (Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        checkBoxState = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        for (int y = 0; y < 14; y++){
            checkBoxState.add(y, false);
        

        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class ViewHolder  {

        ImageView logoImage;
        TextView textName;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        ViewHolder (View v){

            logoImage = v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textName = v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.grid_checbox);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;











        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        }

        final GridWord temp = list.get(position);
        holder.logoImage.setImageResource(temp.logo);
        holder.textName.setText((CharSequence) temp.name);



        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;

        finalHolder.checkBox.setId(position);






        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                status = true;
                if(((finalHolder.checkBox.isChecked()))) {
                    checkCheckBox(position, false);
                    finalHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState.get(position));

                }
                else {
                    checkCheckBox(position, true);
                    finalHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState.get(position));
                }

            }
        });
         finalHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState.get(position));






        return row;
    }


    public ArrayList<Boolean> getCheckBoxState(){
        return checkBoxState;


    }
    public void checkCheckBox(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            checkBoxState.set(position, true);
        else
            checkBoxState.set(position, false);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 }
```

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
    if (isVisible && isStarted) {
        checkList.clear();
        checkList = gridAdapter.getCheckBoxState();
        for (int x = 0; x < checkList.size(); x++) {

            if (checkList.get(x)) {
              // some code


            }


        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to have this arraylist in you activity holding this 3 fragments. Try updating this `Arraylist` from your Second fragment.

This way, whenever you want to read the values in First Fragment, you can read them from this global arraylist and hence so you have single instance of your arraylist.